# Is it correct to say "scratch the edge of the sticker until it sticks up, then pull the sticker off by the edge"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You have a sticker stuck on a surface and you want to take it off.

[image]

[image]

Is it correct to say "**scratch the edge of the sticker until it sticks up, then pull the sticker off by the edge**"?

Comment: I would say "pick at the edge of the sticker with a nail to turn it up, then use that to pull it off".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Michael Harvey's comment, you can say to either **"scratch"** or **"pick at"**, since both refer to using your fingernail to pry at the lip between the surface and the object in question. Once you have a small bit of that object lifted (referred to as the edge in this example), you can then utilize your original phrase

> **"[and] then pull the sticker off by the edge"**

to complete the sentence.

In summary, both

> **"Scratch the edge of the sticker until it sticks up, and then pull the sticker off by the edge"**

and

> **"Pick at the edge of the sticker until it sticks up, and then pull the sticker off by the edge"**

work in this context. It may be more common to use the first instance due to word utilization, but both work grammatically. I also added "and" to your original compound sentence to better link the two independent clauses.